# View where yes/no information from separate rows in grouped into single row with two columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains employees' work shift data. Each row holds employee ID number, whether they clocked in or out and the corresponding datetime of the action. Table `shifts`:

```
+-----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| id  | employeeid | action | timestamp           |
+-----+------------+--------+---------------------+
| 99  | 76         | in     | 2019-01-25 12:20:43 |
| 100 | 76         | out    | 2019-01-25 22:17:22 |
| 102 | 76         | in     | 2019-01-26 10:38:14 |
| 104 | 76         | out    | 2019-01-26 17:00:26 |
| 105 | 76         | in     | 2019-01-27 11:45:35 |
| 106 | 76         | out    | 2019-01-27 14:48:27 |
| 110 | 76         | in     | 2019-01-27 17:33:15 |
| 117 | 76         | out    | 2019-01-28 02:16:21 |
+-----+------------+--------+---------------------+
```

- There can be multiple shifts in the same date for a given employee
- Shift might span from one day to the next
- Entries in column `action` are always in `in`, `out` order

I need to create a view where each shift is represented as a single row, something like this:

```
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| employeeid | in                  | out                 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 76         | 2019-01-25 12:20:43 | 2019-01-25 22:17:22 |
| 76         | 2019-01-26 10:38:14 | 2019-01-26 17:00:26 |
| 76         | 2019-01-27 11:45:35 | 2019-01-27 14:48:27 |
| 76         | 2019-01-27 17:33:15 | 2019-01-28 02:16:21 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

If the last action for the employee was `in` then the out should be NULL

I've read through few posts that combine data from rows to columns but can't find anything that deals with binary situation like that.

Can someone point me in a correct direction on this? Thank you.

Comment: Does the work shift table contain only 1 IN and 1 OUT entry for each employees every day? Or is it possible that there are multiple IN/OUT entries in a day for a given employee?

Comment: There can be multiple in/out events per day per employee or shifts that start on one day and end on next. The software that inputs this information makes sure that there cannot be consecutive IN, IN or OUT, OUT entries.

Comment: @Strawberry adjusted the question for clarity. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous answer looks good but I wondered about two shifts in a day,
or a shift that spans multiple days, and thought maybe id is important.

I assume that the id column is an always-ascending integer primary key.

I assume that nobody can check out without first checking in.

I assume you want "out" to be NULL if someone has checked in but not out.

I assume timestamp is not a reserved word and table name = shifts.

Try:

```
SELECT employeeid,
 timestamp AS "in",
 (SELECT MIN(s3.timestamp) FROM shifts s3
  WHERE s3.employeeid = s1.employeeid
  AND s3.action='out' AND s3.id > s1.id) AS "out"
FROM shifts s1 WHERE action='in';
```

Comment: your assumptions are correct. I adjusted the question for clarity and brought in line with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

A solution without a correlated subquery...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,employeeid INT NOT NULL
,action VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,timestamp DATETIME NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
( 99,76,'in' ,'2019-01-25 12:20:43'),
(100,76,'out','2019-01-25 22:17:22'),
(102,76,'in' ,'2019-01-26 10:38:14'),
(104,76,'out','2019-01-26 17:00:26'),
(105,76,'in' ,'2019-01-27 11:45:35'),
(106,76,'out','2019-01-27 14:48:27'),
(110,76,'in' ,'2019-01-27 17:33:15'),
(117,76,'out','2019-01-28 02:16:21');

SELECT x.employeeid
     , x.timestamp shift_start
     , MIN(y.timestamp) shift_end 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.employeeid = x.employeeid 
   AND y.timestamp > x.timestamp 
 WHERE x.action = 'in' 
   AND y.action = 'out' 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id;
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| employeeid | shift_start         | shift_end           |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|         76 | 2019-01-25 12:20:43 | 2019-01-25 22:17:22 |
|         76 | 2019-01-26 10:38:14 | 2019-01-26 17:00:26 |
|         76 | 2019-01-27 11:45:35 | 2019-01-27 14:48:27 |
|         76 | 2019-01-27 17:33:15 | 2019-01-28 02:16:21 |
+------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You could group the data by the employeid and the date and get the first in and last out datetime with the min & max function nested with an if.

```
/*Example Data*/
create table if not exists EmployeWorkShift(
      id int Primary key auto_increment,
      employeid int not null,
      action  char(3) not null,
      _timestamp datetime not null
)

insert into EmployeWorkShift
value (default , 76, 'in', '2019-01-25 08:20:43')
      ,(default , 76, 'out', '2019-01-25 12:17:22')
      ,(default , 76, 'in', '2019-01-25 13:17:22')
      ,(default , 76, 'out', '2019-01-25 22:17:22')

/*sql query*/
select employeid, cast(_timestamp as date) as _Date, min(if(action = 'in', _timestamp,null)) as _in, max(if(action = 'out', _timestamp,null)) as _out
from EmployeWorkShift
group by employeid, cast(_timestamp as date)
```

**Edited:**

As I know now, the wanted solution is that the query returns one row for every sequence the employee is in the office.
      So if the employee was in the office from  8 am to 12 am and came back again at 13:00 and leaves again at 22:00, there should be 2 rows. 
      I solved it with a window function, you need at least mysql version 8. If you have not mysql version 8 you could solve it with a self join.

```
SELECT employeid, _in, _out FROM (
      SELECT employeid,action, _timestamp as _in, lead(_timestamp) over(partition by employeid order by _timestamp) as _out
      from EmployeWorkShift
) sub
where action = 'in'
```

Comment: I know take a look at the example data I have created. There are multiple shifts on the same day.  Therefore I group by the date, do make it work with multiple shifts in the same date.

Comment: Oh I am sorry, now I understand your problem properly. I will edited the question.